How to route to refresh page in NextJS after revalidation
I have a method to update some data. On update, I want to revalidate the path, route to it and reload (to fetch new data). I tried this:
  const path = `/app/homeworks/${res.slug}`;
  await revalidatePath(path);
  router.push(path);
  window.location.reload();

But window.location.reload() is called before the page changes router.push(path);. How to do this properly? now I have to manually refresh page to see updated data
EDIT
This is a part of my page.tsx
async function getData(id: string) {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/homework/${id}`, {
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return (await res.json()) as Homework;
}

On update, I want to revalidate that path show user the updated state.

Unless you're forcing that page to be static, you don't need to revalidate the path. Just route to it directly. You'll need to share your page's code to give a more complete understanding of what you're exactly trying to do. If you're trying update that path on the fly, you almost surely don't want it to be static.
Edit:
Move that function into the page itself, and make the page async. As long as it's rendered on the server, which all async pages will be, it won't hurt your SEO at all. This is actually better than dynamically rendering on the client when it comes to SEO. Making pages static really only benefits you when you're super concerned about performance, but the benefit is tiny. SSR on demand like this is still far more performant than client side rendering.
const MyPage = async (someProps: Props) => {
async function getData(id: string) {
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/homework/${id}`, {
cache: "no-store"
  })

  if (!data) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  const homework = await res.json() as Homework;


return (
        <div>
    My page stuff
        </div>
    )
}


Yes I force page to be static for SEO purposes

If it's rendering on the server, you don't need to worry about dynamic generation and SEO. That's only an issue when it's client rendered, and the initial code returned to search engine bots isn't the final output that can give them the accurate information that they need.

I added some details to my question. What do you propose to do? I want to make this page seo friendly

I edited my answer as well with a code snippet that might help.

nothing has changed and after removing revalidatePath, new data is not fetched

Pass a const homework = await fetch(..., { cache: 'no-store' }) object to stop fetch from caching data.
